# What is the difference between rdf:_1....rdf_n and rdf:_li?

Tags: rdf

What is the difference between `rdf:_1....rdf_n` and `rdf:_li`?

Can I use these in all rdf container (Seq, Bag, Alt) or not?

Answer (score 4):

The `:_n` properties are equivalent to `:li` elements used in order.   Anywhere where you're using `:_1`, `:_2`, etc., in order, you can use `:li`.  Not only can you use them with all the RDF containers, you can use them with other resources too.

**Note:** This makes it *look* like `:li` is a property, but it's not. It's a special element for the RDF/XML syntax that gets interpreted according to special rules; it's syntactic sugar.  This is similar to how `a` is used in Turtle—`a` itself isn't a property, but the syntax says that where `a` is used like a property, the actual property is `rdf:type`.

From the **RDF/XML Syntax Specification** (emphasis added):

> #### [2.15 Container Membership Property Elements: rdf:li and rdf:_n](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax-list-elements)
>
> RDF has a set of container membership properties and corresponding
> property elements that are **mostly used with instances of the rdf:Seq,
> rdf:Bag and rdf:Alt classes which may be written as typed node
> elements**. The list properties are rdf:_1, rdf:_2 etc. and can be
> written as property elements or property attributes as shown in
> Example 17. **There is an rdf:li special property element that is
> equivalent to rdf:_1, rdf:_2 in order**, explained in detail in section
> 7.4. The mapping to the container membership properties is always done in the order that the rdf:li special property elements appear in XML —
> the document order is significant. The equivalent RDF/XML to Example
> 17 written in this form is shown in Example 18.

Also, from **RDF Vocabulary Description Language 1.0: RDF Schema** (emphasis added):

> #### [5.1.5 rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_containermembershipproperty)
>
> The rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty class has as instances the
> properties rdf:_1, rdf:_2, rdf:_3 ... that are used to state that a
> resource is a member of a container. rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty
> is a subclass of rdf:Property. Each instance of
> rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty is an rdfs:subPropertyOf the
> rdfs:member property.
>
> Given a container C, a triple of the form:
>
> ```
> C rdf:_nnn O
> ```
>
> where nnn is the decimal representation of an integer greater than 0
> with no leading zeros, states that O is a member of the container C.
>
> **Container membership properties may be applied to resources other than
> containers.**

Comment: It should be noted that there is actually no `rdf:li` "property". RDF/XML uses `<rdf:li>` as a special element that maps to the container membership property when used in order, but other serialization formats don't follow this syntax.

Comment: @IS4 That's a good point -- I've updated the answer to try to make that clearer.